# Getting all versions of a specific file in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Given a Team Foundation Server repository, how can I retrieve all checked in versions (or versions later than a specific changeset) of a specific file?

The reason I'm asking is I want to track what versions contain a certain string. So I thought I'd download them all and then grep or similar.

Comment: You can use annotate to some extent for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard way to do it from the UI or the commandline, but it's easy to do from the Client Object Model.

You can use the [`VersionControlServer.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.downloadfile.aspx) method and supply a versionspec. And you can use the [`VersionControlServer.QueryHistory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.queryhistory.aspx) method to query all the different changeset versions of the file.

Combined you'd be able to piece together a small Console application or a Powershell script to grab all versions. And grep them at the same time by adding a bit of Regex :).

Check out [this blog post to see how to connect to TFS and get hold of the ProjectCollection](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/01/make-you-custom-tfs-tools-clever-by.html) from which you can request the `VersionControlServer` object.